# Cakephp - [Oracle] make query to another users table

Tags: sql, oracle, cakephp

I need que make a select query from a table outside my user. I can make the select query from toad for example but in cakephp i get this error:

> Missing Database Table Error: Table cursos for model Curso was not
>   found in datasource ot.

I understand the error occurs because the table doesn't exists directly in my user.

The question is: is there any way to get the data in this situation??

Comment: this is like 2 database different that do you have in your sistem?

Answer (score 0):

look what I understand the problem you have 2 databases and users want to use one for work:

Multiple Database connection issue CakePHP

in your database.php You can configure 2 connections

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host'       => 'localhost',
    'login'      => 'test',
    'password'   => 'test1',
    'database'   => 'test_portal',
    'prefix'     => ''
    //'encoding' => 'utf8',
);

public $test = array(
    'datasource'    => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent'    => false,
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'login'     => 'dfffd_23',
    'password'  => 'dsfsd324',
    'database'  => 'testdbuser',
    'prefix'    => ''
    //'encoding'    => 'utf8',
);

}
```

now in your model you have to specify which of the settings or connections want used for so you can select the users that you want.

```
class Example extends AppModel {
    public $useDbConfig = 'test';
}
```

you can see this in the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#usedbconfig)

Comment: Thanks for aswering, this is te situation. I have my own squema in oracle, lets say "user1" BUT i have to consult "tableX" on "user2" which i have permission to do select querys. So i want to do like a: "select * from user2.tableX" from within "user1"